# VIM g between two search strings

Tags: vim

I have the following general structure repeated in a document I'm editing with VIM:

```
-- Dumping data for table `Blahblah1`

INSERT INTO `Blahblah` VALUES (....
multiple lines of insert statement

-- Table structure for table `Blahblah2`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Blahblah2`;
CREATE TABLE `Blahblah2...
```

I'd like to use a `g[lobal]` search/execute to delete from the line beginning `-- Dump` to the blank line before the line beginning `-- Table` throughout the dump file. (about 25 tables)

What I've got is

```
:g/^-- Dumping/ ,/^-- Table/.-1d
```

Am I close or can anyone offer a better suggestion?

*No I can't re-dump the tables. The database was MySQL and I'm converting it to SQLite manually and I don't have the MySQL db any more -- just the dump.*

---

Essentially, I want this:

```
-- Table structure for table `Blahblah1`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Blahblah1`;
CREATE TABLE `Blahblah1...

-- Dumping data for table `Blahblah1`

INSERT INTO `Blahblah` VALUES (....
multiple lines of insert statement

-- Table structure for table `Blahblah2`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Blahblah2`;
CREATE TABLE `Blahblah2...
```

to turn into this:

```
-- Table structure for table `Blahblah1`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Blahblah1`;
CREATE TABLE `Blahblah1...

-- Table structure for table `Blahblah2`

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `Blahblah2`;
CREATE TABLE `Blahblah2...
```

Comment: That's nice, someone posted an answer then deleted it before I could comment. There are several solutions such as "place cursor on line with `-- Dump` then `d/^-- Table` which I could modify into a macro but they aren't ideal. I'd like to delete from all 25 with a 1-liner as I have about 10 such deletions to perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work if you don't include the `.`:

```
:g/^-- Dumping/,/^-- Table/-1d
```

Also, as noted in the comments, the space before the comma is not necessary.

Comment: Yep, just figured that out too. Actually I did `:g/^-- Dumping/,/^-- Table/-1d` and it worked. Anyone able to comment on whether the space before the `,` matters?

Comment: The space is useless.